# c++ map iterator not looping over every element in the map

Tags: c++, maps

I'm attempting to loop over a std::map I've constructed in c++

The map is fairly strange, the keys are vectors of structs I've created (I've used a custom comparator) and the values are vectors of doubles.

My problem is that when I iterate over the map, the loop terminates before I reach the end.

```
typedef map<int, map<vector<svm_node>, vector<double>, CompareSparseVectors> >::iterator DataIter;
typedef map<vector<svm_node>, vector<double>, CompareSparseVectors>::iterator SVIter;

for(DataIter di = myModel.modelData.begin();
    di != myModel.modelData.end();
    ++di) {
    cout << "The size of (di->second) is " << di->second.size() << endl;
    int itercount = 0;
    for(SVIter sv = (di->second).begin();
        sv != (di->second).end();
        ++sv) {
        cout << itercount << endl;
        itercount ++;
    }
  }
}
```

The output of this code snippet is

```
The size of (di->second) is 47
0
1
The size of (di->second) is 18
0
1
```

myModel.modelData is a `map<int, map<vector<svm_node>, vector<double>, CompareSparseVectors> >` and `ComparseSparseVectors` is a struct containing a comparison function for `vector<svm_node>`. If you need more context, please let me know, but it just seems like I couldn't have a map complex enough that it claims to be one size when queried with `.size()`, yet isn't able to be iterated over completely.

EDIT: Here's the code for the `svm_node` and `CompareSparseVector` structs.

```
struct svm_node{
    int index;
    double value;

    friend bool operator==(const svm_node& a,const svm_node& b) {
        return (a.index == b.index
                        &&
                fabs(a.value - b.value) < 1E-20);
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const svm_node& a,const svm_node& b) {
        return (a.index != b.index
                        ||
                fabs(a.value - b.value) > 1E-20);}    };                                                                                                                                                             

struct CompareSparseVectors {
    bool operator()(const vector<svm_node> a, const vector<svm_node> b)
    {
      if(a.size() != b.size()) return true;
      for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {if(!(a[i] == b[i])) return true;}
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Does `(a<b) && (b<a)` (where by "`<`" I mean your compare function) always return false for any possible `vector<svm_node>`. If you have a bug and this is not the case, then I think you've violated the `map`'s rules.

Comment: I don't have an overloaded < or > function for svm_nodes. I was under the impression that I only needed to override == if that is the only operator I'm using in CompareSparseVectors. I'll add the code for svm_node/CompareSparseVector...

Comment: You don't need to overload "<", but your comparison function should be a binary function that needs to return true if the first argument is less than the second argument. If you did "==", then that's the (or at least a) problem.

Comment: Ohh gosh, I think that might be it then. I for some reason thought that the comparison function was meant to be represent equality rather than less than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `ComparseSparseVectors` returns true if and only if one vector is *less than* the other. You should be able to run:

```
vector<svm_mode> a, b;
cout << (CompareSparseVectors(a,b) && CompareSparseVector(b,a));
```

and get 0 for all possible a and b.